# JPA/Hibernate: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, readonly

I'm using Hibernate 4 with a simple "join table" between two other tables. Here are the JPA 1.0 compatible entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Companies")
public class Company
{
    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PQs")
public class PQ implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

As you can see two similar tables, just a simple ID plus name. Now the interconnecting entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Partnerships")
@IdClass(value = PartnershipId.class)
public class Partnership implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pq_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer pqId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer companyId;

    @Column(name = "ordinal_nbr")
    private Integer ordinalNbr;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pq_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private PQ pq;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company;

    ...
}
```

Note the `... , insertable = false, updatable = false` on `@Column` here.

```
public class PartnershipId implements Serializable
{
    private Integer pqId;

    private Integer companyId;

    public PartnershipId()
    {
    }

    public PartnershipId(Integer pqId, Integer companyId)
    {
        this.pqId = pqId;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    ...
}
```

When running the following test code

```
public class Main
{
    private static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "standalonePu";

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityTransaction trans;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        setUp(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        trans.begin();

        PQ detachedPq = new PQ(1, "Test PQ");
        Company detachedCompany = new Company(1, "Test Company");

        PQ pq = em.merge(detachedPq);
        Company company = em.merge(detachedCompany);

        Partnership detachedPartnership = new Partnership(1, 1, 1);
        detachedPartnership.setPQ(pq);
        detachedPartnership.setCompany(company);

        Partnership partnership = em.merge(detachedPartnership);

        partnership = em.find(Partnership.class, new PartnershipId(1, 1));

        System.out.println("Persistent partnership = ("
            + partnership.getPQId() + ", "
            + partnership.getCompanyId() + ", "
            + partnership.getOrdinalNbr() + ")");

        trans.commit();
        close();
    }

    private static void setUp(String puName)
    {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(puName);
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        trans = em.getTransaction();
    }

    private static void close()
    {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

... Hibernate fails with a really strange exception on `trans.commit();`:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 4
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:90)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 4
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1347)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1280)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:78)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 4
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:80)
    at $Proxy12.setInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2599)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3276)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1084)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 4
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.outOfRangeArgument(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.checkSetParameterIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setInt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:124)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 4
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

The tested configuration is Hibernate 4.0.0.CR4 and HSQLDB 2.0. I've also tested this with MySQL 5 with the **very same** JDBC exception, so obviously Hibernate is generating incorrect code.

The workaround to resolve this is to put `..., insertable = false, updatable = false` onto the relationships' `@JoinColumn`s, but it's not really what I want.

So, is this a Hibernate bug? The above code should be correct from the perspective of JPA...

Comment: Hibernate don't really recommend the use of IdClass and Multiple @Id properties. This would be much nicer if represented using a component type.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your statement? The above is plain JPA 1.0 and Hibernate claims to be JPA 2.0 compatible starting with version 3.5. Note, I want to stay portable here (JPA).

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier

Comment: Oh now I understand your point. But actually I don't care. :-) The question is whether this is correct JPA syntax or not. If it is, then it's time for another Hibernate JIRA...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug:

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/JPA-24

I tested this with the JPA reference implementation EclipseLink 2.3 and it works perfectly.